# Django model for datetime availability

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a sample application to book items from other users. I have hit a road block as I can't seem to figure out how to model when item is available to be rented.

Requirements:

- Users can rent item per day or per hour.
- Owner is able to select dates, hour an item is available.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On the item's model, add two datetime fields, for example "bookedStart" and "bookedEnd". And have a function isBooked() that checks if a given datetime or the current datetime is in that time frame, and return True if it is, or False otherwise.

If the users should be able to add multiple time frames (at once) when an item is available or not, you can make a separate model for it, for example BookedItem, and add in it start and end datetime fields, and foreign fields to the user and item. And again, a isAvailable() or isBooked() function.

Answer (score 1):

If I receive this requirement, I will design a table as below:

```
class RentedItemsList(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(...)
    rented = models.BooleanField(...)
    rent_at = models.DateTimeField(...)
    return_at = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

Description:

- `item` stores name of item.
- `rented` represents status. `1` is available. `0` is unavailable.
- `rent_at` represents when user want to rent someone item. It will update this column.
- `return_at` represents when user want to rent item per day or per hour. It will set deadline.

I think it can help you figure out how to model when item is available to be rented. You can refer it.

It's all up to you how to design API to access model.

Comment: Interesting design difference between this and your code : as an `Item` can be only rented **once** at a time, Tony saw the relationship with `Booking` as a *one-to-one* and thus aggregated the two models. It is nice and simpler, but your code is fine as well : for the cost of one foreign key, you gain the ability to see the booking history of any item. Design is all about choices. :)

Comment: @giant_teapot If you are interesting, I welcome everyone to edit my answer or answer better solution.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fine ! :) Just wanted to emphasize the importance of design choices with regards to the actual features one wants to implement (and it seemed too good an opportunity for OP was asking for design advice).

Comment: The item does not have to be rented out to be unavailable. The owner could simply be on vacation. The owner should be able to select dates when the item is rentable.

Comment: The owner is sure to select dates to return before rented item is deadline. But here is't responsible to assist how to write APIs because you have to figure out yourself by your models. Anyone doesn't know what you want to do.